# InvalidArgumentError: Exception encountered when calling layer | Determined shape must either match input shape along split_dim exactly

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have written some code that is supposed to do some band splitting on some spectrograms, based on  a music source separation paper I read. It basically takes a certain complex valued spectrogram as an input and transforms it into subbant spectrograms. I have written some code in an attempt to do so but I keep getting errors which from what I understand, come from the for loop in the call function. This for loop is meant to concatenate real and imaginary numbers, and then layer normalized and passed through a fully connected layer, which should output the final subband spectrogram. I dont get the error I get (posted fully below) and dont see how I can fix it either

```
import tensorflow as tf

def select_norm(norm, dim, shape):
    if norm == 'gln':
        return tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(axis=dim, center=True, scale=True)
    if norm == 'cln':
        return tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(axis=dim, center=True, scale=True)
    if norm == 'ln':
        return tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(axis=dim, center=True, scale=True)
    else:
        return tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=dim)

class Band_Split(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, temporal_dimension, max_freq_idx, sample_rate, n_fft, subband_dim):
        super(Band_Split, self).__init__()

        step_idx_100 = 100 * n_fft / sample_rate
        step_idx_250 = 250 * n_fft / sample_rate
        step_idx_500 = 500 * n_fft / sample_rate
        idx_1k = 1000 * n_fft / sample_rate
        idx_4k = 4000 * n_fft / sample_rate
        idx_8k = 8000 * n_fft / sample_rate
        self.subband_dim = subband_dim
        idxs_1 = tf.range(step_idx_100, idx_1k, step_idx_100)
        idxs_2 = tf.range(idx_1k, idx_4k, step_idx_250)
        idxs_3 = tf.range(idx_4k, idx_8k, step_idx_500)
        self.idxs = tf.concat([idxs_1, idxs_2, idxs_3], axis=0)
        self.idxs = tf.cast(tf.floor(self.idxs), tf.int32)

        aux_idxs = self.idxs
        aux_idxs = tf.concat([[0], aux_idxs], axis=0)
        aux_idxs = tf.concat([aux_idxs, [max_freq_idx]], axis=0)
        aux_idxs = aux_idxs[1:] - aux_idxs[:-1]

        self.layer_norms = []
        self.linear_layers = []
        for i in aux_idxs:
            self.layer_norms.append(tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(axis=[2*i, temporal_dimension]))
            self.linear_layers.append(tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.subband_dim))

    def call(self, inputs):
        B = tf.split(inputs, self.idxs.numpy(), axis=3)
        Z = []

        for i, (layer_norm, linear_layer) in enumerate(zip(self.layer_norms, self.linear_layers)):
            b_i = tf.concat([B[i][:, :, :, :, 0], B[i][:, :, :, :, 1]], axis=2)
            b_i = tf.transpose(layer_norm(b_i), perm=[0, 1, 3, 2])
            Z.append(tf.transpose(linear_layer(b_i), perm=[0, 1, 3, 2]))

        Z = tf.stack(Z, axis=3)
        return Z

# output should be (batch, temporal, k_chunks, subband_dim) which should be (4, 9, 30, 128)
# Test run
B = 4 # batch
T = 9 # temporal
C = 2 # two channels
F = 257 # frequency
temporal_dimension = T
max_freq_idx = F
sample_rate = 16000
n_fft = 512
subband_dim = 128
hidden_dim = 256

X = tf.random.normal(shape=(B, T, C, F))
band_split = Band_Split(temporal_dimension, max_freq_idx, sample_rate, n_fft, subband_dim)
result = band_split(X)

# X
# result
print(X.shape)
print(result.shape)
```

And the full error message I get is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 16
     14 X = tf.random.normal(shape=(B, T, C, F))
     15 band_split = Band_Split(temporal_dimension, max_freq_idx, sample_rate, n_fft, subband_dim)
---> 16 result = band_split(X)
     18 # X
     19 # result
     20 print(X.shape)

File d:\ITU\BO\DNS\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback..error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

Cell In[6], line 34, in Band_Split.call(self, inputs)
     33 def call(self, inputs):
---> 34     B = tf.split(inputs, self.idxs.numpy(), axis=3)
     35     Z = []
     37     for i, (layer_norm, linear_layer) in enumerate(zip(self.layer_norms, self.linear_layers)):

InvalidArgumentError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'band__split' (type Band_Split).

{{function_node __wrapped__SplitV_num_split_29_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} Determined shape must either match input shape along split_dim exactly if fully specified, or be less than the size of the input along split_dim if not fully specified.  Got: 2524 [Op:SplitV] name: split

Call arguments received by layer 'band__split' (type Band_Split):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(4, 9, 2, 257), dtype=float32)
```